# Spring JPA Projection findAll

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Is it possible to use "findAll" for a JPARepository returning a Collection/List of Projections?
Example:

```
@Entity
public class Login {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String pass;

    (...)
```

}

```
public interface LoginProjection {
    public String getName();
}

@Repository
public interface LoginRepository extends JpaRepository<Login, Long> {
    Login findByName(String name);

    @Query(value = "SELECT name FROM login", nativeQuery = true)
    List<LoginProjection> findAllLoginProjection();
}
```

Using @Query it works! But it is not possible to use

```
 List<LoginProjection> findAll();
```

Because LoginProjection does not extends T (Login).

I was thinking if it is possible to give an "alias" for findAll like findAllXYZ that does the same thing as findAll.
Using filters it works too, but I do not want to use them:

```
 List<LoginProjection> findAllByName(String name);
```

My main goal would be something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface LoginRepository extends JpaRepository<Login, Long> {
    Login findByName(String name);

    List<Login> findAll();

    List<LoginProjection> findAllLoginProjection();
}
```

Which is pretty easy and with "zero @Query"

Comment: List<LoginProjection> findAllProjectedBy();

Comment: You may need to annotate projection interface with the @Projection annotation: @Projection(name = "name" , types = Login.class)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

And add a method to the repository:

```
List<LoginProjection> findAllProjectedBy();
```

The method name can be simplified to `findBy()` to match the documentation example at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: Actually "List<LoginProjection> findAllProjectedBy();" is enough! Thanks

Comment: Applied your comment :)

Comment: All you need is `findBy()` the part between `find` and `By` gets ignored by the query generation.

Comment: @JensSchauder If the part between `find` and `By` does not start with an upper case character, it fails.

Comment: Where did you find that? There's zero mention to "ProjectedBy" at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: @André  I agree.  Where is this voodoo documented????  Upvote for this answer, but no idea how it was figured out or a reference.

Comment: Here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections. If we apply the comment from Jens Schauder and left only findBy(), it will match the documentation example.

Comment: I, probably, need to change my answer and apply Jens' comment.

Comment: I think `ProjectedBy` is specific to OP's question. For all others, the answer is just 'findBy()`.

Answer (score 20):

I assume you're not using [Spring Data REST](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest#overview), so `@Projection` won't help here. @pavel-molchanov showed one form of expressing the projection, another form is:

```
List<LoginProjection> findBy();
```

If you have more than one projection, you can avoid creating a method in the repository for each projection by using [dynamic projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic) like e.g. this:

```
<T> List<T> findBy(Class<T> projection);

// usage e.g.
... = findBy(LoginProjection.class);
... = findBy(UserSummaryProjection.class);
```

Comment: This was helpful.  Here is the anchor/link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic

Answer (score -2):

if you want to be more flexible you can add to the repository this method

```
<T> List<T> findBy(Class<T> projection);
```

and then you can call it with the following

```
List<LoginProjection> rows = loginRepository.findBy(LoginProjection.class);
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can use all the projections you want using the same query